# ASP.NET Boilerplate background jobs abandoned

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am using asp.net boilerplate and running a background job that posts data to an external API.
The post is happening correctly but the background job is still been abandoned instead of deleting it from the backgroundjobs table.

Is there a way to force a successful job execution and only abandon it if it fails.

Code Below

```
using Abp.Reflection.Extensions;
using EErx.Middleware.RestAPIClient.Dto;
using Erx.Middleware.Configuration;
using Erx.Middleware.Models;
using Erx.Middleware.RestAPIClient.Dto;
using Erx.Middleware.TCPCommunicator.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
using System.Text;

namespace Erx.Middleware.TCPCommunicator.Jobs
{
    public class PDStatusUpdateJob : BackgroundJob<PDUpdateJobArgs>, ITransientDependency
    {
        private readonly Log _log;
        private readonly IConfigurationRoot _appConfiguration;
        private readonly IRepository<DispenseMessageHeader, long> _dispenseMessageHeaderRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<DispenseMessageScript, long> _dispenseMessageScriptRepository;
        private readonly IObjectMapper _objectMapper;

        public PDStatusUpdateJob(
            Log log,
            IRepository<DispenseMessageHeader, long> dispenseMessageHeaderRepository,
            IRepository<DispenseMessageScript, long> dispenseMessageScriptRepository,
            IObjectMapper objectMapper
            )
        {
            _log = log;          
            _dispenseMessageHeaderRepository = dispenseMessageHeaderRepository;
            _dispenseMessageScriptRepository = dispenseMessageScriptRepository;
            _objectMapper = objectMapper;
            _appConfiguration = AppConfigurations.Get(
              typeof(TcpCommunicatorModule).GetAssembly().GetDirectoryPathOrNull()
          );
        }

        [UnitOfWork]
        public override void Execute(PDUpdateJobArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                var output = new PDDispenseMessageDto();
                var scriptOutput = new List<PDDispenseMessageScriptDto>();

                var headerRecord = _dispenseMessageHeaderRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MessageGuid == args.MessageGuid);

                var dispenseMessage = _objectMapper.Map(headerRecord, output);

                var scripts = _dispenseMessageScriptRepository.GetAllIncluding(p => p.Items).Where(x => x.DispenseMessageHeaderId == headerRecord.Id).ToList();

                dispenseMessage.Scripts = _objectMapper.Map(scripts, scriptOutput);

                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

                var requestMsg = dispenseMessage.ToJsonString(true);

                var client = new RestClient(_appConfiguration.GetValue<string>("PDUpdateAPI"))
                {
                    Timeout = -1,
                    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true
                };

                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + GenerateToken());
                request.AddHeader("EntityDescription", "ERX");
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", requestMsg, ParameterType.RequestBody);

                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

                if (response.ErrorMessage != null)
                {
                    _log.Logger.Error(response.ErrorMessage);
                }
               

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _log.Logger.Error(e.Message);
            }


        }

        public static string GenerateToken()
        {
            var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("somestring"));
            return encoded;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `UnitOfWork` attribute will automatically rollback the transaction after a short period of time. Are you 100% sure the method is finishing correctly?

Comment: I dont actually need unit of work as I am not making any db changes. I will remove that.I can confirm that the api post finishes correctly.